# How to pass array to a class in php?

Tags: php, class

```
 class User{     
      public $name ;
      public $age ;
      public $height ;
      public $weight ;   

      function __construct($name,$age,$height,$weight){      
          $this->age = $age;
          $this->name = $name;
          $this->height = $height;
          $this->weight = $weight;
     }

     public function ispis(){       
         echo $this->age;       
     }

}

$question_array = [new User ("Ivan","22","174","68"), new 
User("Luka","23","174","68") ];

$daniel = new User($question_array);

//$daniel = new User("ivan","22");

$daniel->ispis();
```

So when i call this function ispis() it doesn't do anything but when i echo inside function __constructor it shows correct values of everything entered. Also when i comment first three lines above   //$daniel = new User("ivan","22"); line and uncomment this, ispis() works just fine. Would be nice if someone could explain to me  why this is happening. Tnx in advance :)

Comment: `$question_array` is an array of `User` objects.  So what exactly are you expecting `$daniel = new User($question_array);` to do?

Comment: You have defined 4 parameters on your constructor while you are passing only one to the last user instance ??? 4 parameters are expected ?

Comment: how do you mean im passing only one? there are 4 parameters inside new User()@LotfioLakehal

Comment: Also, there is no way that `$daniel = new User("ivan","22");` "works just fine". Depending on your version of PHP, you are, at best, getting a Warning, if not a Fatal Error.

Comment: i want it to print every passed argument fore every object but in a function ispis() @PatrickQ

Answer (score 4):

By the looks of your code you're trying to pass two new User instances into a new user ("daniel").

So basically User is expecting 4 arguments (age, name, height, weight).  You've created Luka and Ivan correctly, but you're passing those two Users as arguments when trying to create Daniel. You're giving it Luka and Ivan when it wants age, name, height and weight.

If you simply want to pass an array to the constructor, just pass it as an argument on the new instance:

```
<?php
class User {

    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $height;
    public $weight;

    function __construct($args){

        $this->age = $args['age'];
        $this->name = $args['name'];
        $this->height = $args['height'];
        $this->weight = $args['weight'];

    }

    function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }
}

$question_array = [
    'name' => 'Daniel',
    'age' => '22',
    'weight' => '174',
    'height' => '68'
];

$daniel = new User($question_array);
echo $daniel->getAge(); // 22

?>
```

Comment: Note now that the constructor accepts one argument `$args`, which gives no indication or hint as to what a User object requires upon creation.

Comment: @Progrock yes, not exactly how I’d do it personally but the question is “How to pass an array to a class in php”

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears a little ambiguous, but perhaps you want to create an object from an array of arguments.

```
<?php
class User {

    public $name;
    public $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age  = $age;
    }

    public function echoAge()
    {
        echo $this->age;
    }
}

$args  = ['Leonard', 21];
$bones = new User(...$args);
$bones->echoAge();
```

Output:

```
21
```

Answer (score 1):

Robert just answered, and his method is one that i use in a personal MVC to define construct or in another way there is also this method that i use always in my MVC :P...
Btw i think Ivan you are doing some confusion with classes...

```
class User{

public $name ;
public $age;
public $height ;
public $weight ;

 function __construct($array){

    if (is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $k=>$v){
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
     }

  }
  public function ispis(){

      print 'NAME :' .$this->name .' AGE : ' .$this->age.' HEIGHT : ' .$this->height .' WEIGHT : ' .$this->weight.'<br>';

  }

}

 $arrayOne = ['name'=>"Ivan",'age'=>"22",'height'=>"174",'weight'=>"68"];
 $arrayTwo = ['name'=>"Luke",'age'=>"23",'height'=>"174",'weight'=>"68"];

  $ivan = new User($arrayOne);
  $luka = new User($arrayTwo);
  $ivan->ispis();
  $luka->ispis();
```